# Android Auto is not working with Realme1 (6 GB / 128 GB)

Tags: android-auto, oppo-coloros

I have Sony XAV-AX5000 in my car, I tried to run android auto with my realme1 (6GB /128 GB) variant but it is not woring in both colorOS 5.2 and colorOS 6.

I checked with other phones (iphone as well), Android auto and Apple car play both are working fine as expected.

Comment: Are you using a quality USB cable? (trust me, this matters) Is your phone running the most current OS version? Is the Sony stereo updated to the most recent firmware? See link below [https://us.community.sony.com/s/question/0D50B00005IMvLxSAL/android-auto-not-working-in-ax5000-with-realme1-phone?language=en_US](https://us.community.sony.com/s/question/0D50B00005IMvLxSAL/android-auto-not-working-in-ax5000-with-realme1-phone?language=en_US)

Comment: Yes everything is latest and I am using standard quality cable.